# Sqlalchemy query against list of dict

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, sqlalchemy

I am trying to run a query that filters results depending on a list of dict.

Lets be clearer...

I have a table Heading, each Heading has a version field

```
class Heading(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50), nullable=False)
    version = Column(Integer)
```

On the other hand, I have a list of dict that looks like this (Json formatted):

```
"headings": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "version": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "version": 1
    }
]
```

I want to execute a query on the Heading table that exclude rows where the version in the database is equal to the version in the (json) list.

I tried executing something like this:

```
res = Heading.query.filter(~Heading.id.in_([d['id'] for d in headings if d['version'] == Heading.version])).all()
```

With a database looking like this (Json formated again, sorry ):

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Heading1",
    "version": 2,
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Heading2",
    "version": 1,
}
]
```

But it returns the Heading2 row anyway. Basically, I want the query to return all the rows that are not defined in the Json AND the rows that have a newer version in the DB.

I dont know if my question is clear enough.
Maybe It is not the right approach, please let me know

Thanks in advance for any help

**EDIT:**
The generated Raw SQL is so:

```
SELECT heading.id, heading.name, heading.version
FROM heading
WHERE heading.id = heading.id
```

So there is an obvious problem with the sqlalchemy query but I cant figure out what...

I think it is coming from the part

```
if d['version'] == Heading.version
```

But I don't know how to reformulate this condition elsewhere in the query

Comment: Can you post the Raw SQL query as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you've suspected the problem is with the

```
[... for ... if d['version'] == Heading.version]
```

Though `d['version'] == Heading.version` produces an SQL expression object, Python then uses its truth value for filtering:

```
In [9]: bool(headings[0]['version'] == Heading.version)
Out[9]: False
```

and so your list-comprehension results in an empty list. A `Heading.id` could never be in an empty list, so

```
~Heading.id.in_([])
```

will simply evaluate to true:

```
In [10]: print(~Heading.id.in_([]))
1 = 1
```

Given that your DB supports [composite IN queries](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.tuple_) the solution is to compare against *(id, version)* tuples:

```
In [9]: from sqlalchemy import tuple_

In [10]: session.query(Heading).\
    ...:     filter(~tuple_(Heading.id, Heading.version).in_(
    ...:         [(d['id'], d['version']) for d in headings])).\
    ...:     all()
Out[10]: [<__main__.Heading at 0x7f840cc8ae48>]

In [11]: _[0].name
Out[11]: 'Heading1'
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer, this is much more elegant than the solution I found. Will reuse those composite IN queries for sure.